# How to fix: compairing result of a bigquery query to a list

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I am a newbie in Python, I appreciate all help. 
I want a list of activities of a group, who purchased for 4$ this way: `purchase_date(1,1,0,1,1,0,1)` where `purchase_date` is the date of the purchase, and the `arrays indeces+1` gives the days after the purchases. 1 means active day, 0 means not active day. 
E.g. `20190203(1,1,1,0,0,0,1)` means the purchase was on `2019-02-03`, and the user was active after that on 4th, 5th, 6th and 10th of February.

I tried the code below.
Steps:

1. Created a datatable with the purchases: `four_dollar_buyers(user_pseudo_id,purchase_date)`. Queried it and loaded the result into the `four_dollar_purchases` list.
2. Iterated over on `four_dollar` purchases
3. Made 2 helper arrays:
   `seven_days_date` contains the dates after the purchases
   `seven_days_number` should contain ones and zeros (active or not in given 
   day)
4. Iterated over the `seven_days_date`, made a query from datatables of the 
   given date, what gave the id-s of the active users on that day. Load the 
   result of the query into a list named '`actives`'
5. If the `user_id` of the given purchase is in actives, then the 
   `seven_days_number` array should change from 0 to 1 on the given index.

```
client = bigquery.Client(project="project")

QUERY = ('SELECT * FROM `project.four_dollar_buyers`')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)                             
four_dollar_purchases = list(query_job.result())                        

for row in four_dollar_purchases:                                       

  seven_days_date = ["","","","","","",""]                          
  seven_days_number = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]                                   

  for i in range(7):
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%Y%m%d')                 
    date_time_obj = date_time_obj + timedelta(days=1)+timedelta(days=i)         
    seven_days_date[i] = date_time_obj.strftime("%Y%m%d")                   

  for idx, days in enumerate(seven_days_date):

    QUERY = ('''SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id FROM 
    `project.events_'''+days+'''` WHERE event_name IN 
    ("activity_added")''')
    query_job = client.query(QUERY)
    actives = list(query_job.result())                          


  if row[0] in actives:                                 
    seven_days_number[idx] = 1                              


  print(row[1] + str(seven_days_number))
```

There is no error message anymore, but all result is like this `20181212(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`. 
So for some reason the helper array does not change, after the purchase date it gives only zeros.
I checked the variables row[0] and actives with pprint and both of them contains the right result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query_job = client.query(QUERY)
actives = list(query_job.result())

for dict in actives:
  if dict[0] == row[0]:
    seven_days_number[idx] = 1

print(row[1] + str(seven_days_number))
```

Comment: Please explain why this is the appropriate solution to the question. The goal is to do more than toss out code, it's to educate so the OP knows what to do when a similar situation occurs.

Comment: Thx, that's the solution. Disclaimer for other readers:
Incmiko realized that my code compared list elements to a list of dictionaries, because the result of the query was a dict from which I made a list after.

Answer (score 0):

Days is not an integer type as ralaxpy has suggested. So, you can use enumeration or something else in order to modify the list using the index.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it as edited the code in the question. No changes.:/

Comment: Is row[0] in actives true? Also idx must be a value between 0 and len(seven_days_number), otherwise you wont notice any changes